# [SOLVED]How to test Angular custom elements and do coverage in module ngDoBootstrap

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, custom-element

[image: [Module Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTgsU.png)]

- I would like to complete coverage in my module but can seem to find a way of referencing/spyOn the `customElements.define` inside the bootstrap.

bonus:

- help with the useFactory coverage would be much appreciated.
- this test pass so far.

```
  it('initializes', () => {
    const module: AppModule = TestBed.inject(AppModule);
    expect(module).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('ngDoBootstrap', () => {
    const module: AppModule = TestBed.inject(AppModule);
    spyOn(module, "ngDoBootstrap");
    module.ngDoBootstrap();
    expect(module.ngDoBootstrap).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

[RESOLVED]
[image]

Comment: Answering to my self from personal account:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RESOLVED]

```js
describe("AppModule", () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        AppModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(APP_ROUTES),
      ],
      providers: [
        DynamicComponentService,
        RouterHelperService,
        Router,
        Injector,
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

  });


  it("ngDoBootstrap", () => {
    const module: AppModule = TestBed.inject(AppModule);

    spyOn(module, "ngDoBootstrap").and.callFake(() => {
      const appModule = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {
        injector: TestBed.inject(Injector)
      })

      customElements.define("custom-element-name", appModule);
    }).and.callThrough();
    spyOn(customElements, "define");

    module.ngDoBootstrap();
    expect(module).toBeTruthy();
    expect(module.ngDoBootstrap).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(customElements.define).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
})
```